# Help with sh files on Mac

Tags: mac, command-line, python

I am analyzing a data set and preparing it for preprocessing and I am back into computer science after some time so bear with me ( I am a Mac user)

I am trying to run this sh file that will not run due to errors about its directory not existing. Can someone provide me with some insight as to how to get this code running on a Mac (Apple Silicon)?

It is part of a group of files from [GitHub](https://github.com/TIMAN-group/covid19_misinformation/blob/master/data/README.md#download-the-coaid-dataset).

It contains the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# get tweets
python3 extract_real_and_fake_tweets_coaid.py --data_type 1 # real
python3 extract_real_and_fake_tweets_coaid.py --data_type 2 # fake

# get dataset
python3 pip generate_full_dataset.py full_dataset_label_ids.csv coaid_tweets_real.csv coaid_tweets_fake.csv

# merge datasets for deFEND
python3 merge_claim_tweets_fake.py
python3 merge_claim_tweets_real.py
python3 merge_news_tweets_fake.py
python3 merge_news_tweets_real.py
```

Here are the errors :

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/josehuertas/merge_claim_tweets_fake.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/josehuertas/merge_claim_tweets_real.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/josehuertas/merge_news_tweets_fake.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/josehuertas/merge_news_tweets_real.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
josehuertas@Joses-Macbook-Pro ~ %
```

Comment: how do i get this to run, i am getting errors about its directory not existing i looked uip some commands that were supposed to help bu i am unsure

Comment: The shell script looks fine, the issue most likely is coming from the python part. Can you add the actual errors you get by copy/pasting them from Terminal into the question?

Comment: Where did you store the python files, where did you store the shell script, in which directory are you in Terminal when running the script?

Comment: i see that it terminal is generally accessing my user file... i think i would need to re direct to the folder containing the sh file

Comment: As @nohillside points out, you need the python files too, which should be in the current directory, since the script does NOT provide a path to them.

Comment: I mean the terminal directory is set to where all of the python files are located... meaning it has access to them .... but it still insists that it cannot find the .py files

Comment: Are the python files stored directly in your home folder?

Comment: no they are stored in a sub folder in my desktop ... /Users/josehuertas/Desktop/Dataminingproject/CoAID

Answer (score 1):

The shell script tries to access `/Users/josehuertas/merge_claim_tweets_fake.py`, so if the python files are stored somewhere else it will fail.

Possible solutions:

- specify the path to the python files within the shell script (`python3 ~/Desktop/Dataminingproject/CoAID/extract_real_and_fake_tweets_coaid.py` etc.),
- add a `cd ~/Desktop/Dataminingproject/CoAID` at the beginning of the script,
- move the shell script to `~/Desktop/Dataminingproject/CoAID`, `cd` into that directory and run the script from there.